# Separation of variables in Schrodinger equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, linear-pde

I am trying to solve the following PDE, subject to a highly unconventional boundary condition:

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial x}=i m \frac{\partial^2 p}{\partial y^2}$$

$$\frac{\partial p}{\partial y} (x,0)=k \sqrt{x} p(x,0)$$ 
$$p(x,\infty)=1$$
$$p(0,y)=1$$

I tried using separation of variables, but the first boundary condition leads to a condition that can't be satisfied.

Does anyone know the trick or how to approach this exercise?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have $p(x,\infty) = 0$?

Comment: Yes! it is $p(x,\infty)=1$

Comment: Please be explicit about the region where you are solving.

Comment: Well, it's a "complex" diffusion equation (1D), so we are solving along a line, thinking about y as the spatial variable and x the time variable

Comment: Can anybody help?